# How do I resolve the 'permission denied' error while running `conda install nb_conda`?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I'm new to Jupyter Notebook and was trying to install Notebook Conda to help manage environments with the command, `conda install nb_conda` but I'm getting this error every time I run it.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this problem by running the command as an administrator:

> Press Win -> type "cmd" -> right-click onto "Command Prompt" -> Select
>   "Run as Administrator" -> Enter the command again

An alternative would be to install Anaconda into your user's folder "C:\users\\Anaconda". Writing to files withing "C:\ProgramData" usually requires administrator priviledges, writing to your user's folder does not.

Comment: thank you for the solution, worked with the Administrator access.

Answer (score 0):

if you will run  anaconda prompt as administrator it will solve the error. I was facing the same problem it solved when I ran the prompt as administrator